# Can't get addEventListener() working without adding onclick event as an attribute in button tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code works if I use an onclick event, but my online lesson says I can't use one, but the code does not work without it. I need to find another to collect the data.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="activity2.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input name="data" id="data" placeholder="Enter text" type="text">
        <button type="submit" id="submit">Click</button>
        <p id="replace">Replace this text.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", collect);

function collect() {
    var info = document.getElementById("data").value;
    document.getElementById("replace").innerHTML = info;
}
```

Comment: Is that the full code of your page? If so, you don't need a submit button, use `<button type="button">...`

Comment: What does the error console say? Search for the error and use the responses to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Chances are your javascript is running before the page has loaded.  If the element with the id "submit" does not yet exist when you add the event listener, then obviously there won't be a DOM node with a listener on it.  Then, after the listener has been "added", a DOM node is created without an event listener.

So, you just need to run the javascript after page load:

```
window.onload = function () { 
    document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", collect);
    function collect() {
        var info = document.getElementById("data").value;
        document.getElementById("replace").innerHTML = info;
    } 
}
```

Or put the script at the end (or do both):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input name="data" id="data" placeholder="Enter text" type="text">
        <button type="submit" id="submit">Click</button>
        <p id="replace">Replace this text.</p>
        <script src="activity2.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this jquery script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("submit").click(function(){
       var info = document.getElementById("data").value;
       document.getElementById("replace").innerHTML = info;
     });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Dave, the window.onload thing worked.